# Excel Dynamic Drop Down Menu

Tags: excel

Hi I'm just wondering if there is a way to in Excel have a drop down menu that changes with the number of entries in the column.

I am currently using:
*Data - Data Validation - List*, to create my drop down menu.

As I am adding more entries below the Source range of the List I was wondering if there is a way to dynamically update this range? I have written VBA forms and can achieve a similar result using those but I am just wondering if this can be streamlined by not having a form popup for my search.

Also is there a way to have entries only added to the list based on a condition?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a dynamic named range.  So let's pretend you have a worksheet specifically designated for your dynamic drop-down list source.  We'll call the sheet "List" and we'll put the entries in column A starting in cell A1.

Now create a named range (we'll name this range `listData`) with this formula:

```
=List!$A$1:INDEX(LIST!$A:$A,MATCH(REPT("z",255),LIST!$A:$A))
```

Steps to create a named range: Go to Data -> Named Range -> New

Now for your data validation list, simply set it to the named range:

```
=listData
```

Comment: Another method that I got to work was using `=A:A` as the Source range. I got yours to work as well but it seemed easier to just use my way. Haven't tested the flaws of using either method for what I'm doing but thanks.